# Spliting pdf file into multi pdf files with same look and feel

Tags: php, pdf

I am using the following php function to split a pdf file into two files according to page number. 
The source file has 14 pages. I am creating the two files: First 12 pages for one and the last two pages for the second fils. 
But I am getting a different site format for the both created files than the source file. 
How can I improve the function to make sure that I am getting the exact site format as the source file?
I am using the pdf-reader library. Or what could you recomment to use as tool to reach this?

```
function split_pdf14($filename, $end_directory = false, $numberOfPages = 12, $row) {
    $pdf = new \TCPDI();
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filename);
    $pagesDone = 0;
    if ($pagecount > $numberOfPages) {
        $maxFiles = floor($pagecount / $numberOfPages);
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++) {
            $new_pdf = new \TCPDI();
            $new_pdf->setSourceFile($filename);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfPages; $i++) {
                $pagesDone++;
                if ($pagesDone > $pagecount) {
                    /*
                     * do nohting
                     */
                } else {
                    $new_pdf->AddPage();
                    $new_pdf->useTemplate($new_pdf->importPage($pagesDone));
                }
            }
            try {
                if ($j == 1) {
                    $new_filename = 'localfiles/' . $row['f_auftragsnr'] . '_' . $row['t_sorte'] . '_' . $row['t_sprache'] . '_' . $row['t_umfang'] . '.pdf';
                } else {
                    $new_filename = 'localfiles/' . $row['f_auftragsnr'] . '_' . $row['t_sorte'] . '_' . $row['t_sprache'] . '_' . $row['t_umfang'] . '_BON.pdf';
                }
                //$new_pdf->Output($new_filename, "F");
            $new_pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $new_filename, 'F'); 
               //$new_pdf->Output('/home/box/public_html/box2019/' . $new_filename, 'F'); 
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
            $numberOfPages = $pagecount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you write "site format". Each page in a PDF file consists of content that is added at fixed positions. Splitting a document, should not change the appearance of a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the default page format (A4) and orientation.

Your code doesn't care about the size of the imported pages and simply adds A4 portrait pages:

```
$new_pdf->AddPage();
$new_pdf->useTemplate($new_pdf->importPage($pagesDone));
```

You simply have to add the pages in the correct size and orientation:

```
$tplId = $new_pdf->importPage($pagesDone);
$size = $this->getTemplatesize($tplId);
$new_pdf->AddPage($size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P', [$s['w'], $s['h']]);
$new_pdf->useTemplate($tplId);
```

PS: The script you are using (TCPDI) seems to be several years old. You may use the latest official version of [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) for such task.